# Start and later only refresh activity from service

Tags: android, service, android-activity

My service currently listens to phone calls and then starts an activity via startActivity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, CallMonitor.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
intent.putExtra("call", call);
startActivity(intent);
```

So, when the service receives more phone calls, more activities will be started.

But I want that the service only starts a single activity. The next time it should send the call to the already started activity. And the activity updates itself.

What is the best approach?

Alexander  Miehlke, Berlin

Answer (score 2):

you should use **intent.addFlags(intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT)** that will call the already started activity and will bring back it to the front. and  in that activity you should override the onResume() method. and for updating that activity based on intent you passed on, you should override onNewIntent() method to set the newly received intent. for e.g.

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    setIntent(intent);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    callString=getIntent().getExtras().getString("call");
    //your code
}
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Hmm, I have tried your solution, but everytime I call startActivity() a new activity is started and the onCreate() method is called.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of testing, the solution is just a single line in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity
    ...
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    ....
</activity>
```